# Visual Studio 2013 ignores nuget.config

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project that uses Nuget. I have a packages.config file in the root directory of the solution, defining the Nuget packages we want installed. I also have a nuget.config file in the root directory of the solution, defining packageSources, as well as some packageSourceCredentials. One of the package sources is a private repo for our company.

If I open a command prompt in that root directory of the solution, and type `nuget restore` it works fine, and is able to hit our private repos to pull in some of the custom packages we use.

But if I open the solution in Visual Studio 2013, and build it, it fails when trying to download our custom packages, because apparantly it is ignoring our nuget.config file, and thus does not know about our private nuget repo.

I could go into Tools > Options and add our private repo, but we're trying to do everything within the solution itself, so that it builds out-of-the-box with no custom configuration needed.

Why is nuget.config being ignored by VS 2013?

Comment: I assume you're already aware that Nuget searches for it's NuGet.config files in this order:
1. .nuget\nuget.config
2. walks up recursively from that project-folder to the root.
3. the global NuGet.config which is expected to be at %appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config

That last is your machine-wide (per user) file, in Users\{user-name}\roaming, and that is the file that is effected when within Visual Studio you go into Tools > Options and add your private repo. Thus, you can access that within PowerShell or whatever.

Comment: @JamesWHurst Are you saying Visual Studio will never honor the nuget.config information in my project, and instead I need to use PowerShell to modify the global nuget.config file to add the repo instead?

Comment: Does it work if you move your nuget.config from the same folder as the solution to a subfolder called .nuget (thus .nuget\nuget.config)?

Comment: @TimLewis I had avoided that because based on what I've read, that .nuget folder is considered the "old way" of doing things, and shouldn't be necessary with the latest versions of Nuget and VS. Right? Re: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore (Updated my link, first one was wrong.)

Answer (score 18):

Restart Visual Studio after editing NuGet.config!

I've noticed that VS2012 doesn't pick up on changes to NuGet.config until after I restart it.

Comment: I believe this was the issue in my 2015 Project as well. I thought I had restarted at some point and it still didn't register, but after it started working I did some thorough tests and everything was working as expected as long as I restarted VS.

Answer (score 3):

I created a new project with the following directory structure.

```
-ConsoleApplication1
    -ConsoleApplication1
    -ConsoleApplication1.sln
    -nuget.config
```

Prior to adding the nuget.config I could not see any of my private repos when using the Manage Nuget Packages For Solution feature.
When I added the nuget.config I was able to see my new repos in the dialog window. I am also able to restore my packages using nuget restore and from a build within VS 2013.

My nuget.config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="MyRepo" value="http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:81/host/repo" />
    </packageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Based on your described issue the only thing I can think is that you may have previously attempted to disable Nuget Package Restore from your project prior to using the up to date method of restoring packages. If you don't carpet bomb package restore from every project simultaneously some logic could be left over that may interfere with the new method. For example, if you deleted the .nuget folder from your solution the nuget.config file could still be in there causing conflicts.

Comment: How would you manage the nuget.config file in VS 2013 if it's "above" your current solution directory? Can you elaborate on your directory structure in terms of where your nuget.config file is, in regards to where you .sln and .csproj files are? And what does your Solution Explorer view look like, can you see the nuget.config file then?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would one need to place nuget.config above the solution directory, where, logically, it would apply to all solutions. That can't be right...

Comment: I believe it completely makes sense to place it above your solution. We have our main solution file in the root of our trunk and our regular NuGet.config is in there. However, we also have a separate /Devs/UserXxx folder structure under trunk where our devs have their own solutions. The problem is those solutions don't respect the package locations. Also our solution uses projects from a completely different repo which should have their own packages folder.  However, NuGet doesn't allow two package locations from one solution so we have to create a common 'packages' location for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you have a multi-project solution, with the projects all in folders under the solution folder, putting the NuGet.config in a project folder doesn't work. It doesn't pick up the private package source. It *does* work if you put a NuGet.config in the solution folder.

That is, this *doesn't* work:

- Solution

  - ProjectA

    - ProjectA.csproj
  - ProjectB

    - ProjectB.csproj
    - NuGet.config

while this *does* work:

- Solution

  - ProjectA

    - ProjectA.csproj
  - ProjectB

    - ProjectB.csproj
  - NuGet.config

I *also* found that the `disableSourceControlIntegration` option does not work when specified in `\NuGet.config`. It only works when in `.nuget\NuGet.config`. So I have two config files for my solution, one at the root which holds the package source configuration, and one in the `.nuget` folder with the `disableSourceControlIntegration` option.

Tested with Visual Studio 2012 Update 5 and NuGet Package Manager extension 2.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Is under your solution Web Site project or Web Application project?
I think that web site project ignore nuget.config file.